# ImageJ silent mode - process without opening images

Tags: java, plugins, imagej

I need to run Macro, but I don't want to show the image. If I don't call the imp.show(), ImageJ will print to the console There are no images open. So how can I run Macro without showing the image? Thanks in advance.

```
public class MyPlugin implements PlugIn {

public static void MyPlugin(String path) {
    System.setProperty("plugins.dir", "libraries/plugins");
    System.setProperty("macros.dir", "libraries/macros");
    Opener opener = new Opener();
    ImagePlus imp = opener.openImage(path);
    imp.show();
    IJ.run(imp, "Skeletonize", "");
    runMacroFile("libraries/macros/FindJunctions", "");
    imp.close(); 
}
```

Comment: What's the content of your macro file `libraries/macros/FindJunctions`? Consider asking your question to the [ImageJ mailing list](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/list.html) as well, it will get the attention of a lot more ImageJ users and experts than here.

Answer (score 3):

- If you make your macro an **ImageJ command** by putting the file into any subfolder of `plugins/` (e.g. `plugins/macros/Find_Junctions.ijm`, see the [ImageJ documentation](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-14.html#toc-Section-14)), you should be able to run:

  `IJ.run(imp, "Find Junctions", "");`

  where `imp`is your current image. However, this doesn't prevent commands within the macro to display images, unless the macro itself sets `setBatchMode(true)`.
- A safer way to avoid displaying images is to avoid calling the macro at all, and to include all commands of the macro into your plugin. You can get the required command syntax by running the [macro recorder](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub%3aRecord...) in Plugin mode.

Since your code example doesn't compile, and you don't supply any details about the macro you want to call, I can't help you much further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried to put the file into plugins/ and change command to IJ.run(imp, "Find Junctions", ""}, but it still prints: There are no images open. The Macro file is from this page http://image.bio.methods.free.fr/ImageJ/?Angiogenesis-Analyzer-for-ImageJ&artpage=3-5&lang=en I have rename it and at the top of the macro I wrote "findTheNodes ();" and "analyseFromATree ();" because these two functions I need.

Comment: As an ImageJ toolset, Gilles Carpentier's _Angiogenesis Analyzer_ heavily relies on the presence of a user interface, and therefore requires an image to be open and displayed. I'm afraid the only way to achieve what you want is to dig into the `findTheNodes()` and `analyseFromATree()` functions and essentially **reimplement** their commands in Java. However, since in your own code you already make sure there is a binary skeleton (you're running `Skeletonize` just before the macro), you can leave out quite some macro code that deals with checking the preconditions...

Answer (score 3):

Add `setBatchMode(true);` to the beginning of your macro. See [built-in macro functions](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#setBatchMode).